# Capacitor discharging dilemma!

Tags: voltage, current

Let us take a capacitor charged by a source voltage of 12 V d.c. supply. Having fully charged, the capacitor is now connected with a source voltage of 5 V d.c. supply.
What will happen to the potential differences(if any other thing happens can mention) of both the capacitor and d.c. supply?
Note:- No other resistor is their in the circuit, the resistance of connecting wires is negligible. There are only two components capacitor(charged to 12 V) and the other d.c. source power supply(5 V) connected in series.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ideal components, the capacitor will discharge into the power supply until the capacitor reaches 5V. Yes, this means that the supply will have a negative current. This is **not** a violation of reality; this is the technique used to charge rechargeable batteries (although that uses controlled conditions rather than just shoving a capacitor across it).

Comment: What if the battery is not rechargeable?

Comment: The energy will still be pumped into the battery. How the battery reacts depends on the exact chemistry, but enough energy will result in injury or death. Those warning labels are there for a reason.

Comment: Could you please explain this pumping of energy in the battery and its reaction using an example of the battery which converts a.c. supply into d.c. supply?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "battery which converts AC to DC". Batteries are electrochemical devices which always generate DC.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the 12V is presented to the 5V supply. What happens next depends on the design of the supply. For example, if there is a diode on its output, current cannot flow back into the supply and the capacitor will remain at 12V.

If it's a simple linear regulator, you will reverse-bias its output transistors. This may cause damage or it may be protected (e.g. http://www.linear.com/product/LT3082 claims reverse current protection as a feature).

Switch-mode power converters may shut down, or allow current into the input stage if it's lower than 12V. For AC-input designs, you may have [image: this kind of circuit]. Again the diode prevents reverse current flow.

Ignatio's answer has dealt with the case of batteries, which will either be recharged or damaged depending on their construction.